# How to install tcltk in R?

Tags: r

My system is: debian6 + r-2.15.

I have installed `tcl-devel` and `tk-devel` with `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
> library("tcltk") 
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: Tcl/Tk support is not available on this system
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘$.tclvar’, ‘$<-.tclvar’, ‘as.character.tclObj’, ‘as.character.tclVar’,  
‘as.double.tclObj’, ‘as.integer.tclObj’, ‘as.logical.tclObj’, ‘as.raw.tclObj’, 
‘print.tclObj’, ‘[[.tclArray’, ‘[[<-.tclArray’, ‘$.tclArray’, ‘$<-.tclArray’, 
‘names.tclArray’, ‘names<-.tclArray’, ‘length.tclArray’, ‘length<-.tclArray’, 
‘tclObj.tclVar’, ‘tclObj<-.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue.default’, ‘tclvalue.tclObj’,
‘tclvalue.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue<-.default’, ‘tclvalue<-.tclVar’, ‘close.tkProgressBar’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’
> install.packages('tcltk')
Warning message:
package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)
```

How can I install `tcltk` in my R?

---

#### Edit

```
> capabilities()["tcltk"]
tcltk 
FALSE
```

I compiled R-2.15.1 to install it on debian6.04, but how can I do now in order to run `tcltk`?

Comment: I thin if you install R with `--with-openblas` it should solve the problem. At leat on my mac it did the job. I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/2683)

Comment: Have no idea why, but on R 3.4.0 capability returned false, but on 3.4.4 it returned true, and therefore it did work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are doing this wrong.

Read the README at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ to learn how to get the current R version for your Debian version (be it stable or testing).  This version *already has* support for the `tcltk` package which comes with R, provided R is built the right way.  Which is easiest to assure with a proper pre-built version.

You can check that by looking at `capabilities()`:

```
R> capabilities()["tcltk"]
tcltk 
 TRUE 
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code on centos, You need to modify it according to your system.

First, install `tcl` and `tk`:

```sh
# on centos
sudo yum install tcl-devel tcl
sudo yum install tk-devel tk
```

Second, compile R with `--with-tcltk`:

```sh
./configure --enable-R-shlib=yes --prefix=`pwd` --with-x=no --with-tcltk
```

Third, install package.