# Tktable : could not be found in R

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I try to use tcltk in R, but the package Tktable could not be found.

```
> library("tcltk")
Loading Tcl/Tk... OK
> tclRequire("Tktable")
[1] FALSE
Warning :
In tclRequire("Tktable") : the package Tcl 'Tktable' is not found
```

When I install R (r-base-core) all this linux package are installed too :

```
tcl                     install
tcl-dev                 install
tcl8.5                  install
tcl8.5-dev              install
tcllib                  install
tk                      install
tk-dev                  install
tk8.5                   install
tk8.5-dev               install
tklib                   install
```

I tried to install manually libtktable2.9, and those packages are automatically installed :

```
libtktable2.9:i386          install
tk8.4:i386                  install
tcl8.4:i386                 install
```

I tried the fonction addTclPath in R (with different path, because I dont really understand where is the tcl location...), but nothing changes.

I saw similar posts on few forums but no answer yet.

Any idea?

Comment: Waht is you OS ? did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875307/how-to-install-tcltk-in-r?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned my OS : it's Ubuntu 12.04. I read the post you mentioned but it is not the same problem. The package tcltk is installed on R.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: It had been included as part of the `tcltk2` package, but this is no longer the case. There the `tablelist` package is provided. This package is used within `gWidgetstcltk` too, as it avoids this issue of installation and still provides a reasonable widget for editing cells.

Answer (score 3):

http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/affylmGUI/#testBWTk describes installing Tktable.

> To install Tktable download from http://tktable.sourceforge.net. From
>   this site, select "File Distributions, select the "tktable" link,
>   select the latest version (currently 2.10), then select the tar.gz
>   file (currently "Tktable2.10.tar.gz"). Save it to a suitable location,
>   unzip and untar it (Example command is "tar zxf Tktable2.10.tar.gz").
>   look in the Tktable directory and read the README.txt file
>   installation instructions.

To get Tktable to install on debian, I installed this first

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev mesa-common-dev libjpeg-dev libtogl-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I could just install the package `tk-table`

```
sudo apt install tk-table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for documentation purposes for other readers:

> Windows users should be aware that the Tcl extensions ‘BWidget’ and
>   **‘Tktable’ which are included with the R for Windows installer** are
>   extensions and do need to be declared. ‘Tktable’ does ship as part of
>   the Tcl/Tk provided on CRAN for Mac OS X, but you will need to tell
>   your users how to make use of it:
>
> ```
>  > addTclPath('/usr/local/lib/Tktable2.9')
>  > tclRequire('Tktable')
>  <Tcl> 2.9
> ```

So there is no need for an extra tcl/tk or tktable installation.

Source: http://www.pqr-project.org/R-exts.html