# Tktable package is not available in R version 4.0

Tags: r, version, distribution, data-fitting, tktable

I'm trying to run the fit.cont function of the rriskDistributions package over a vector of data. However, the result is:

```
library(rriskDistributions)

sales <-
  c(2, 4, 5, 10, 9)

data <-
  fit.cont(sales)

Error in fit.cont(sales) : 
  Tcl package "Tktable" required. Please install it.
Además: Warning message:
In tcltk::tclRequire("Tktable") : Tcl package 'Tktable' not found
```

Apparently, with the version 4.0, R doesn't install Tktable like in the previous versions.

Is there any way to fix this problem without having to get back to the previous version of R?

Comment: This was a packaging error on Windows.  You will get it if you install R-patched from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html

Comment: I uninstalled and then installed with that one, but now the error is a "Session Aborted". It shows the evaluation of each distribution function in  the console, but doesn't show the GUI and inmediatly requires the abortion of the session.

Comment: When I try your example, it doesn't work because I don't have `sales`.

Comment: It can be any vector of data, with any vector the function doesn't work for me. It always go to "Session aborted". I put a vector as an example in the post, even with those, I have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this response to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357481/11761901

Per my own testing version 2.10 is now available.

```
addTclPath('/usr/local/lib/Tktable2.10')
tclRequire('Tktable')
<Tcl> 2.10
```