# Installing R package gsubfn

Tags: r, centos

I am trying to install the latest version of gsubfn from source file on my CentOS machine. It installs with out any issues as follows:

```
> install.packages("/home/ravishankarr/PraaS/gsubfn_0.6-6.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package 'gsubfn' ...
** package 'gsubfn' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (gsubfn)
```

However, when I load this package, I get the following message:

```
> library(gsubfn)
Loading required package: proto
Could not load tcltk.  Will use slower R code instead.
```

What does this warning message mean? Does this slow down the codes using this package? If so, is there a way to get rid of this? Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think you need `tcltk` capabilites.  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875307/how-to-install-tcltk-in-r

Comment: We are currently using the R distribution provided by Vertica. So I really cannot use R distributions from CRAN. capabilities()["tcltk"] throws a FALSE. Is there a way to add tcltk capabilities to an already installed version of R?

Comment: Yes, as the message says it will run slower because it will substitute R code for tcltk.  Whether this is ok for your appli'n or not will depend on what you are doing.  Run it & see if its fast enough. As your R distribution was not built with tcltk capabilities if you want to be able to run tcl/tk based code you need to get a different R distribution. You cannot add such capability after R was bullt.  See gsubfn FAQ: https://code.google.com/p/gsubfn/#TROUBLESHOOTING   You can have multiple versions of R installed at same time.  All standard builds of R have tcltk capacity out of the box.