# R freezes when trying to load tcltk package on MacOS

Tags: r, load, package, tcltk

I tried to load the packages `aplpack` and the console stay frozen with message `Loading required package: tcltk` as follow:

```
> library("aplpack")
Loading required package: tcltk
```

and I eventually had to reload RStudio

I also tried the following command as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875307/how-to-install-tcltk-in-r):

```
capabilities()["tcltk"]
```

But it also freezes and I also had to reload RStudio

I also tried to install `tcltk-8.5.5-x11.pkg` from this [website](http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) but it didn't help

Apparently `tcltk` is an inherent compound of R according to [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-loading-aplpack-library-td4721616.html)

According to the webpage of the packages on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aplpack/index.html), the packages has juste been updated ("published: 2018-06-12"). The authors of the packages might have updated the packgage after the issue reported [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-loading-aplpack-library-td4721616.html)??

here are the specifications:

- RStudio Version 1.1.447
- MacOS 10.13.5
- R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)

Any idea?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: The exact same problem here, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

if I remember well, I managed to install 'Xcode' in R. Let me know if it works